# R: Does R know if code is being executed as script or in a open R session (terminal)

Tags: r, terminal, session-variables

I have code which sometimes I execute from within Rstudio, which has a nice plotter window. But the other times I execute it on a distant machine per command line.

Thus, I would like to know if there is some R environment variable that tells me if I am running code in an open terminal or via Rscript. If yes, I could decide to print the plots into a file or standard out.

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `?interactive` command.

Comment: Great! That is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks a lot.  `fromScript <- !interactive() `